# Cannot scroll on Strike MultiSelect element using Lightening component Salesforce

Tags: javascript, html, css, salesforce-lightning

When trying to scroll thru picklist of multiselect element the whole picklist disappears, so I am unable to scroll the picklist.

```
<c:strike_multiSelectPicklist label="Responsible for" value="{!v.contact.Process_Responsibility__c}" class="responsibleFor">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.processResponsibilityOptions}" var="option">
        <c:strike_option label="{!option}" value="{!option}" />
    </aura:iteration>
</c:strike_multiSelectPicklist>
```

And this is the Strike Multiselect implementation I am using: https://gist.github.com/JitendraZaa/6b82ee00c45a4b1b66093966c5e6583b

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I somehow fixed it at least for my need: had to change this:

```
 handleOnblur: function(component, event, helper) {
        var isMobile = component.get('v.isMobile');
        var eventSourceId = event.target;
        var mobileInputId = 'strike-multi-select-' + component.get('v.idNumber') + '--mobile';
        var shouldCloseMenu = ((isMobile && eventSourceId == mobileInputId) || !isMobile);

        if (shouldCloseMenu) {
            helper.closeMenu(component);
        }
    },
```

to

```
     handleOnblur: function(component, event, helper) {
        var isMobile = component.get('v.isMobile');
        var eventSourceId = event.target;
        var mobileInputId = 'strike-multi-select-' + component.get('v.idNumber') + '--mobile';
        var shouldCloseMenu = ((isMobile && eventSourceId == mobileInputId) || !isMobile);

        if (false) {
            helper.closeMenu(component);
        }
    },
```